# Symfony2 Route global {_locale} requirements

Tags: routes, yaml, symfony-2.1

I have in my routing.yml specified the parameter _locale requirements in every single route and I think that must be something to simplify this situation.

routing.yml

```
ProjectBaseBundle_index:
    pattern:  /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|es

ProjectBaseBundle_privacy:
    pattern:  /privacy/{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:privacy }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|es

.....

ProjectBaseBundle_legal:
    pattern:  /legal/{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:legal }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|es
```

I am using Symfony2.1 beta 3

**Is possible to specify a global _locale requirements for all my routes?**

Comment: On which version of Symfony are you working?

Comment: Symfony 2.1, I do not mentioned because I thought that was a "old" functionality of the framework

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have discovered a way to do that:

Using a "master" routing to import the routing config. As my bundles usually have too much information, I have been separating the controllers, resources and routes in differents "modules". As result of that approach, I have discovered this:

**Master routing.yml**

```
ProjectBaseBundle_default:
    resource: "@ProjectBaseBundle/Resources/config/routing-default.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/project/
    requirements:
        _locale: en|es|de|fr
```

**Child routing-default.yml**

```
ProjectBaseBundle_default_privacy:
    pattern:  /privacy
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:privacy }

ProjectBaseBundle_default_legal:
    pattern:  /legal
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:legal }

ProjectBaseBundle_default_usage:
    pattern:  /usage
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:usage }
```

With this routing config, I minimize the places where need to write the locale requirements.

Comment: This is very usefull. But I wander. What if I wanted one of the locales to be default (say 'es') so that I could have routes like /project/privacy (pointing implicitly to the 'en' locale) while I still have de explicit /{_locale}/ ... routes for other locale. Is there a way to say that in the 'master' routing.yml?. I've been trying with a default _locale ... but turned to be a wishfull thought. regards

Comment: I have not found how to do that. Once you import one route with the /_locale/ parameter before, is necessary to use it.

Comment: What if we want to have a different parameter, other than `_locale`? Something like `country`? `_locale` is a special name for symfony and behaves in a different way...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/6oxsa7whBps

It seems that it is possible to do something similar to what you need, only that the {_locale} parameter is specified at the beginning of the route, not at the end. Also you would need to be running beta 4 of the 2.1 version of symfony (according to Fabien)

Comment: I have seen this discussion, but is dated in June 2011