# Variable on a prefix on symfony2 routing

Tags: symfony, routes

I need a variable on a prefix on my symfony2 routing so that i can do something like this in the main routing file:

```
//app/config/routing.yml
god:
    resource: "@Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /god/{religion}
```

and then something like this in the bundle routing file:

```
gods_route_to_heaven:
    path: /path_to_heaven
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:God:show }
```

so that i can access paths like this:

```
/god/Christianity/path_to_heaven
/god/Islam/path_to_heaven
/god/Hinduism/path_to_heaven
```

and so on.

If i type `app/console route:debug | grep api` on the console i get the correct route `/god/{religion}/path_to_heaven`, so the route is being generated correctly.

But when I try to get the parameter in the controller by placing it as an input in the action function like this:

```
public function showAction($religion)
```

the path gets corrupted and dumping the paths i see it gets duplicated: `/god/{religion}/path_to_heaven/{religion}`

So how would i get the $religion variable from inside the controller?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
//app/config/routing.yml
god:
    resource: "@Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /god
```

and then something like this in the bundle routing file:

```
gods_route_to_heaven:
    path: /{religion}/path_to_heaven
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:God:show }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes that works, but i was trying to avoid having to put the {religion} placeholder in every rout under /god... Imagine i have 100 routes under /god, i would have to add the {religion} placeholder to each one. If instead i add it to the prefix i would only add it once.

Answer (score 1):

the possible solution you need, would be:

File: src/Acme/CoreBundle/Twig/PathExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

class PathExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    private $request;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        if ($event->getRequestType() === HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            $this->request = $event->getRequest();
        }
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'path_route' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getPath')
        );
    }

    public function getPath($name, $parameters = array())
    {
        $parameters = array_merge($parameters, [
            'religion' => $this->request->get('religion'),
        ]);

        return $this->router->generate($name, $parameters, false);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'twig_path_route_extension';
    }

}
```

Configuration as service:

File: src/Acme/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    twig.path_route_extension:
        class: Acme\CoreBundle\Twig\PathExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
        arguments: [@router]
```

Set your routing options:

File: app/config/routing.yml

```
_acme_religion:
    resource: "@AcmeCoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /god/{religion}/
```

Then you can use it in the templates and the routing.yml, for ex:

```
_religion_pathheaven:
    path:     /path_to_heaven
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeCoreBundle:System:getpathheaven }
```

Then, in your templates, you can use:

```
<a href="{{ path_route('_religion_pathheaven') }}">
  Link Path to heaven.
</a>
```

References:

[Pass path parameters automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332115/pass-path-parameters-automatically)
http://blog.viison.com/post/15619033835/symfony2-twig-extension-switch-locale-current-route

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this problem in this way-

```
god:
    resource: "@Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /god/{_locale}/
```

no need to change in here--

```
gods_route_to_heaven:
    path: /path_to_heaven
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:God:show }
```

modification in here--

```
    public function showAction(){
       // below line is extra if you need
         $post   = $this->get('request')->request->all();
         $religion = $post['religion']; 
    }
```

I didn't test this code but all process is well proved. If you will see any problem let discuss.

Also you may see this question it will help you very much [Symfony2 Route global {_locale} requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781287/symfony2-route-global-locale-requirements)

Comment: Yes, that could work, but it's not the best way. What if i wanted to use the _locale for it's real purpose? _locale is a special parameter...

Answer (score 0):

May be it's to late, but it can help other people
I'm facing the same problème with Symfony and FOSUserBundle.
In FOSUserBundle the profile link are :

> site_url/profile/
>  site_url/profile/edit
>   site_url/profile/change-password

I have an admin and dashboard panel, and I want the links to be in admin panel

> site_url/admin/profile/
>  site_url/admin/profile/edit
>   site_url/admin/profile/change-password

and in the user dashboard

> site_url/dashboard/profile/
>  site_url/dashboard/profile/edit
>   site_url/dashboard/profile/change-password

To get this behavior it's very simple without EventListener and TwigExtesion
Here the solution:

replace

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

by

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
fos_user_registration:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix:   /{prefix}/profile 
fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix:   /{prefix}/profile
```

In a template use:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show', {'prefix': 'dashboard'}) }}">Show Profile</a>
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit', {'prefix': 'dashboard'}) }}">Edit Profile</a>
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_change_password', {'prefix': 'dashboard'}) }}">Change Password</a>
```

Or any other prefix you want 
Now if you use for example the change password link you will get this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some
>   mandatory parameters are missing ("prefix") to generate a URL for
>   route "fos_user_change_password".") in
>   FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword_content.html.twig at line
>   3.

you can add the prefix in the template like so:
replace

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_change_password">
```

by

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_change_password', {'prefix': app.request.attributes.get('prefix') }) }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_change_password">
```

this will give you this error

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("prefix") to generate a URL for
>   route "fos_user_profile_show".

the final solution that I found is to override the controller
just copy the hole controle in your app controller folder,change the namesapce and replace

```
if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }
```

by

```
if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show',array('prefix'=>$request->get('prefix')));
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }
```

in the form you don't need the action so it will be

```
<form  {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_change_password">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the religion value like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function showAction(Request $request){
   $yourReligionIs = $request->get('religion');
}
```