# Global URL parameter in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm trying to get a 'global' parameter into my routing, like this:

`/{foo_id}/controller/{another_id}/action`

So there's a Foo object, that has id foo_id, that's used by all controllers in all requests (except the home page)

I tried to implement this by simply adding a foo_id parameter to every route. But then I have to add code for loading the right foo to every single controller in the project, and then I have to make sure a user has access to the Foo in every single controller as well. I found [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781287/symfony2-route-global-locale-requirements), so I changed my routing to something like this:

```
foo:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing-foo.yml"
    prefix: /{foo_id}
    requirements:
        foo_id: \d+
```

And I added a new controller that's inherited by all other controllers:

```
class BaseFooController extends Controller
{
    protected $foo;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $foo_id = $request->attributes->getInt('foo_id');
        // ... set $this->foo ...
    }
}
```

My though was that I'd just be able to use $this->foo in all other controllers to access the Foo object. I could add access control in this controller as well. But it seems like foo_id isn't accessible at this point.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: One way would be to use events. Take a look at this chapter about [creating before and after filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html). When using the dispatcher you can access the current route as well as it's parameters.

Comment: @Artamiel: Thanks, I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to make this with Symfony 2 framework. But you can make a simple script which analyses your routing.yml files with help of regex and adds line "prefix: /{foo_id}" to each route, just after the resource line.

Comment: How would this help? I'm already importing everything using the /{foo_id} prefix so I don't need a script to do that, but I don't want to have to add code for loading the Foo in each and every function in every controller.